# SQL selecionar a partir último día 25

Tags: php, sql-server

Deseo poder selecionar el último día 25 mediante php.

Es decir si estamos a 30 de julio que `$date = 25-07-2018` pero si estamos a 20 de julio me muestre `$date = 25-06-2018.`

```
$¿asistencia = "SELECT * FROM asistencia "+
               "where id_usuario=$Id_usuario "+
               "AND asistencia ='1' AND fecha >= '2018-07-25'";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seleccionas en función del día actual

```
if (date("d")>25) {
    echo date("Y-m")."-25";
} else {
    echo date("Y-m", strtotime("- 1 month"))."-25";
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias me fue muy util

Comment: Un placer @Claus :)